# android List View adapter and send the item object to another activity

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am trying to create note application to practice..
And I have an issue that I tried to search  a lot about it but I can't find exactly what I want.
Simple, I want a list view with all the notes (ArrayList of objects from database) and that list view show the title of the note.
and then when I click one of the items in the list to open another activity that shows the title and the content.
So far I have this code.
This is the class of notes

```
    public class notesTable {
    public  int id;
    public String title;
    public String content;

    public notesTable(){

    }
    public notesTable( String title,String content){

        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;

    }
    public notesTable(int id, String title,String content){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + ". " + this.title;
    }
}
```

and this is the .xml file that has the listview

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/notesLV"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

and this is the .java file for the activity

```
    ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_home);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesLV);
    ArrayList<notesTable> notes_list = db.getAllNotes();

    noteAdapter adapter = new noteAdapter(this, notes_list);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesLV);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent i = new Intent(notesHomeActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("noteObj", lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the noteAdapter class

```
public class noteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<notesTable> {
public noteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<notesTable> notes) {
    super(context, 0, notes);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    notesTable note = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView noteTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteTitle);
    TextView noteContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteContent);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    noteTitle.setText(note.title);
    noteContent.setText(note.content);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Ok, So far the list is shown very good but I want to move to the detail activity and send the selected object to that view to show the details or at least send the id 
how can  I do that ???

this line is giving me error

```
i.putExtra("noteObj", lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement Parcelable in your `notesTable` class:

```
public class NotesTable implements Parcelable {
    public static final Creator<NotesTable> CREATOR = new Creator<NotesTable>(() {
        @Override
        public NotesTable createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new NotesTable(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public NotesTable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new NotesTable[size];
        }
    }

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String content;

    public NotesTable() {}

    public NotesTable(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public NotesTable(int id, String title, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public NotesTable(Parcel parcel) {
        this(parcel.readInt(), parcel.readString(), parcel.readString());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(content);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + ". " + this.title;
    } 
}
```

You'll now be able to pass it in an Intent.

I do need to point out a few things about my example though:

- The naming scheme in Java is `ClassName` and `variableName`. Each "word" in a class name is capitalized, including the first. With a variable, it's the same, but with the first letter made lowercase. It makes it easier for us and you to read if you follow this.
- Please pay attention to formatting when you write your code. As with my first point, it makes it easier for us to read and understand, and will make it easier for you to refer to in the future. If you can't do it while you're programming, Android Studio has the nifty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> which will take care of formatting for you.
- In keeping with the first point I made, I renamed your class from `notesTable` to `NotesTable`. Click your current class name in your IDE and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (replace F6 with 6 on Linux and maybe macOS) and rename your class to `NotesTable`. Then you will be able to copy and paste what I've posted (although I recommend at least reading through it).

Comment: thanks for these useful tips
But still the big problem is not solved yet.
Now I have to create "Parcable Creator" any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Done. Check the new `CREATOR` field.

Comment: Thank you very much for following with my problem.. now the NotesTable has no errors but I still have the problem in i.putExtra("notesObj",lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
The problem is saying: cannot resolve method putExtra(String,Object).........
lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2) is not object??????????????

Comment: Cast it: `(NotesTable) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2)`